# Check if integer divided by 2. SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift

im absolutely new to development, and trying to learn swift.

Right now i know how to make random number, and my next step is:
Im trying to understand how to check if my random number (127) could be divided by 2 without decimals ?
I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 7):

There is a specific API [isMultiple(of:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/3127688-ismultiple) in Standard Library for this purpose

```
let random = Int.random(in: 0..<100)
let isEven = random.isMultiple(of: 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use operator `%` - remainder operator

example:

```
if randomNumber % 2 == 0 {
  print("\(randomNumber) is even")
} else {
  print("\(randomNumber) is odd")
}
```

Comment: Привет) Спасибо большое что ответил.

Comment: Я ввел то что ты сбросил и заменил "randomNumber" на мое число (127), но после того как нажал "Run" в консоли - ничего не произошло.

Comment: @StanislavKonovalov this international version of StackOverflow by rules only English can be used. you can use https://ru.stackoverflow.com/  to discover answers on your language.
Also, you can try updated code, it will print your number with info of is it even or odd.